# Neutrality of tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I recently came across the tag [guacamole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guacamole), whose tag wiki sounds somewhat promotional. Is there a general policy of neutrality in tag wikis, and if so, should this tag's wiki be rewritten?

Comment: That's copied word-for-word from [the home page of the website](https://guacamole.apache.org/). It's more a plagiarism issue than a spam issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of policy, promotional content in a tag wiki is simply poor practice. The tag will really only be seen by people who are already using this technology, or - as an important secondary use case - people who are using something else entirely and need to figure out quickly from the short tag description that this is not the correct tag for them to use.

As already alluded to in a comment, ad copy in a tag description is often an indicator that the tag description is problematic (probably a lazy copy/paste from some overtly promotional page than an out-and-out attempt to use Stack Overflow for promotion) and should be edited.

I believe you should already be able to suggest tag description edits at your privilege level.

The content did not strike me as overtly promotional, but again, as noted in TheWanderer's comment, it is plagiarized, and needed to be edited for that reason. I made a quick stab but invite your review: [main tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33342769/revisions), [short description](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33342770/revisions).

Comment: I do not actually use `guacamole`; rather I saw this tag being used in a new question, clicked on the tag to get more info from the tag wiki, and came across the text that I asked about earlier. Other than the "supports standard *renmote* desktop protocols" typo it looks good to me, but again I have not actually used guacamole.

Comment: Ooops, thanks for catching that!